# Enable R (RLANG) in SAS Studio for OSX (virtual box)

Tags: r, macos, sas, virtualbox, sas-iml

I have installed SAS Studio in OSX via virtualBoxVM. All seems working except making R run from SAS, which is what I am looking for. 
Running :

```
  proc options option=RLANG;
  run;
```

I get

```
SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.4  TS1M3
NORLANG           Disables SAS from executing R language statements.
```

Changing the Autoexec file to:

```
-RLANG
-config "/Users/me/SAS/SAS_Base_OpenSrcIntegration/sasv9.cfg"
```

does not make the trick. Neither changing configuration files...

Any ideas on how to activate RLANG in OSX?

Comment: Are you using SAS UE? If so, it's not designed to allow R to run from SAS.

Comment: Yes, I am using SAS UE, in OSX. So it seems that there is no way to allow run R from SAS in that edition? No by means of any "trick"?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It is a locked down VM so you can't access cfg file. If you search on Analytics U forum you'll see similar questions and answers.

Comment: Great, so thank you very much. Any other way to install SAS on OSX and access R from it?

Comment: Are you at a University? You can usually get a full version for free if you are. Otherwise none that I know of. You can try WPS, 30 day free trial, otherwise $1500.

Comment: Thank you again. I will wait some days in case somebody finds an unexpected way to find the answer, and if not, i will make the answer solved (as impossible).

Comment: So for SAS UE the solution to the question is that it is not possible, because for that version RLANG is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the RLANG option in the .cfg file, not the autoexec.sas file.  Once you do that, restart the SAS server so that it picks up the config change.

I don't have a configuration like this.  Let me know if you have problems.

EDIT:
You can find the default configuration file in

```
*SASHOME*/SASFoundation/9.4/nls/sasv9.cfg
```

The exact location will depend on where SAS is installed, version, etc.  In general, look for the `NLS` folder under `SASFoundation`.

Comment: Yes, I did that in a config file and tried to reference it in the autoexec file, but with no success. It is not clear how to add/modify configuration files when working on VirtualBox. Any idea about how to modify conf. files?

Comment: You cannot reference a config file in a autoexec.sas file.  SAS needs to already by running before it can use the SAS code in your autoexec file.

Comment: Seems that the solution to the question is that it can not be done, because the SAS version is the SAS UE.